# Trouble with \hfill not going to the end of the page

Tags: documentclass-writing, hfill

I am new at creating a class file to maintain a specific format for my resume. I included all the code from the template I am using to prevent any compiling issues.

I am trying to line up my dates at the very end of the page using \hfill, but LaTex is not letting me and I have no idea why. I included sample code and can edit the question if it isn't clear. Thanks!

main.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\name{Random Name} % Your name
% % if you do not have a website, sub your github instead.
\address{(111) 111-1111 \\ San Antonio, CA} 
\address{\href{mailto:randomemail@gmail.com}{randomemail@gmail.com} \\ \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/random/}{https://www.linkedin.com/in/random/} \\ \href{https://github.com/random}{https://github.com/random}}

\begin{document}
    \rSection{Example Title}
    \subfile{sections/firstsection}
\end{document}
```

sections/firstsection.tex

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\rSubSectionWork{Math tutoring for living, Company Education Services}{Mar 2021 - Present}
\begin{itemize}
    \setlength\itemsep{0pt}
    \item Provide tutoring and technical support for students in the Fintech Bootcamp. iuiuniuniuniuniu
    \item This is sentence one with a lot of text for me to test this out please.
    \item More text that will include everythgin and anything for a long time because ai will be the future of the test and they will increase the funding for the thing.
\end{itemize}
\rSubSectionWork{R\&D Engineering Technician, Amazon website}{Jan 2019 - Mar 2019}\\
\rSubSectionWork{Project Contributor, Goldman Sachs grouphhnhh}{Sept 2015-June 2016}
\end{document}
```

resume.cls

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
% \setlist[itemize,1]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=black,
}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
     \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \colorbox{black}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\MakeUppercase\bfseries\color{white} #1}}\\ % Section title
}

\newenvironment{rSubSection}[1]{ 
  \textbf{#1}
}

\newenvironment{rSubSectionWork}[2]{ 
  #1 \hfill #2
}

% ATTEMPTED TO SET UP A ENVIRONMENT
\newenvironment{resumeitem}[1]{
  \begin{list}
    \item{#1}
  %  \newline
  % \vspace{-2pt}
  \end{list}
}


%   \sectionlineskip
%   \hrule % Horizontal line
%   \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
%     \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} % Margin within the section
%   }
%   \item[]
% }{
%   \end{list}
% }

% % SECTION FORMATTING 
% \RequirePackage[nostruts]{titlesec}
% \titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{0.5em}{0em}
% \titleformat{\section{\colorbox{}{}{}{}{\color{black} \scshape \raggedright \large}{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-0.75em}\hrulefill]


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
%  {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
%  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
%   \\
%   {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
%   }\smallskip
%   \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
%   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
%   }{
%   \end{list}
%   \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
% }

% \newenvironment{rSubsection}



% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\LARGE} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\medskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section

% \newenvironment{rSection}[9001]
% \section*{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bfseries\color{white} Education}}}
```

My desired output is at the separation at the bottom of the image with the job title at the left section and the dates at the very end of the right section.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STTfI.png

[image: Desired output at the bottom of the image]

Comment: Also, my original file didn't require \begin{document} for the subfile so I don't know why. I included it so it can work and I can mimic my original error.

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but hardly any of it related to hfill, you could probably have posted a two-line example showing `a \hfill b` not working as you expect.

Comment: It is hard for me to break down the template I am using without creating more errors so thats why I included all the code. I tried to delete some of the code, but then it wouldn't compile.

Comment: too much is better than too little, but this is too much, but I answered anyway:-)

Answer (score 4):

The end of paragraph has `\parfillskip` which is balancing `\hfill` you can end the paragraph with no skip

```
\newenvironment{rSubSectionWork}[2]{%
  #1 \hfill #2{\parfillskip=0pt\par}%
}
```

Note the `%`

als then remove the `\\`  after each use of this command.

Beware adding spurious spaces, You are adding lots of bad space

for example

```
\newenvironment{rSubSection}[1]{ 
  \textbf{#1}
}
```

is

```
\newenvironment{rSubSection}[1]{SPACE
  \textbf{#1}SPACE
}
```

you need `%`  at ends of lines.

Also

```
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
```

defines `\\SPACE` in a form that means that `\\`  will generate an error if not followed by a literal space character.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Now I have new LaTex concepts to go over.